# Why the .bashrc file is not invoked after a sudo command?

Tags: linux, bash

I switch to another user using the command:

```
sudo -u dsc -i
```

After the command executions moves to the home directory /home/dsc .

However, the .bashrc file in this directory is not executed.  Why this happens?

Comment: There are 110,011 questions in Stack Overflow about the bash shell

Comment: Ok, for the next question, for this one already got a good answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo -i` starts a *login* shell; `.bashrc` is only executed for *non-login* interactive shells. One of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile` should have been executed, though.

Comment: And, often, the last action of a login script will be to source the non-login script to ensure it has a consistent environment.

Comment: If I put into .bash_profile . .bashrc then the .bashrc would be invoked, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `su -l` as well as `sudo -i` was indeed not loading the `.bashrc` file.
However, after I added a `.profile` file (in this case at `/root/.profile`) that loads the `.bashrc` file when present, everything works fine

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```